# Is it legal for private citizens to "impound" e-scooters?

Tags: california, theft, trespass, extortion

[This](https://www.theverge.com/2019/7/24/20696405/dockless-scooters-share-repo-men-repossessor-lawsuit-tow-yard-lime-bird-lyft-uber-razor) recent article from The Verge claims that two men in San Diego have create a repo company that impounds e-scooters from companies like Lime, Bird, Lyft, Uber and Razor.

However as far as I can tell these guys are doing this entirely on their own accord. They don't have a license from the city. They write "tickets" in their own system and charge their own rates. They are called not by police but by random business owners.

To me this sounds like straight theft and extortion. Is this something they are legally allowed to do? The article claims that they are now being sued by all these big corporations, but it's unclear to my why this is being treated as a civil matter and not a criminal one.

Comment: Interesting related stories: https://www.nbcsandiego.com/news/local/Scooters-Impounded-San-Diego-Comic-Con-Day-After-513041381.html  https://www.smdp.com/over-100-scooters-impounded-in-first-six-months-of-pilot-program/174230

Comment: And another pair: https://richmondbizsense.com/2019/07/11/flipping-birds-flock-impounded-scooters-headed-auction/ & https://www.columbiatribune.com/news/20190626/bird-retrieves-flock-from-mu-impound

Comment: This one is even more interesting from a legal perspective, Scooter company made a DMCA claim: https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2019/01/bird-sends-nastygram-reporter-describing-lawful-re-use-impounded-scooters

Comment: There's also an issue where property owners don't actually own the sidewalk portion of their property. It is owned by the local city/township typically about 15 ft from the road side. The property owner is however legally responsible for maintaining that space.

Comment: In most cases, the property owners own it, but an easement comes along with the property. There's no citations for this and it doesn't add or expand on the other answers.

Comment: +1. Sidewalks are the real question.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Maybe, Hence the Lawsuits

In the absence of clear statute law these all circle around tort law. For the scooter companies, [trespass to chattels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass_to_chattels), and for the affected landowners (who hire the removalists) [trespass to land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass_to_land) and nuisance seem applicable.

In essence, I can’t take your stuff (trespass to chattels) but you can’t leave your stuff on my property (trespass to land) or impeding access to it (nuisance). If you do, I am entitled to the reasonable costs of dealing with it. Note that, as owner, you remain responsible for you stuff even if you rented it to someone else.

Both sides are pushing hard into unexplored areas of law so we await the judgement with interest. Then we’ll know.

Comment: Folks have been having cars parked without permission on private property towed for years. Wouldn't there be a fair amount of precedent from that?

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant yes, the scooter owners will be arguing it’s not applicable I’m sure. It seems like it would be but there’s enough of a difference that it might be distinguished

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant A person is supposed to mitigate the damage they suffer from another's tort against them.  Unlike a car, a regular person can trivially remove a scooter from their property and place it on public property.  If there isn't an ordinance against them doing that or some other confounding factor, the scooter companies could argue that claiming the impound fees is an unnecessary expense and only serves to try to punish the scooter companies, which is contrary to a plaintiff's responsibility to reasonably mitigate damages.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian that's a cogent point, or at least it would be if was a matter of 1 or 2 scooters left on private property now and then. However, (as pictured in the article linked to in the OP) it can be an ongoing problem with dozens of scooters left on private property and significantly impairing its use.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian *can trivially remove a scooter from their property and place it on public property*, that would depend on the size of the property and how far into the property the scooter is located.

Comment: Taking up the car example, what happens if someone rents a car and parks it on the sidewalk or something? Differently from a car though someone can just pick up a lawfully parked scooted and drop it in the middle of the street to incriminate the last user.

Comment: @lucasgcb, I believe that scooter companies, or at least some of them, ask users to take a photo of where/how they leave the scooter when parking them. If that's being done, the user would at least have some defense.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can see the App simply recording the last location when the ride for that user ends, but really it is a big mess in either case and I won't be surprised if the whole concept gets simply banned.

Comment: @lucasgcb GPS tracking isn't necessarily that accurate. I track my bicycle rides with a pretty good GPS device but it's very often a few meters out and that's plenty enough to be the difference between being on your property versus in a public space.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian and if the inconvenienced owner is disabled, or a child, or physical unable or unwilling to move the scooter. Or, if they injure themselves doing so? Hiring a professional seems eminently reasonable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96662/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-is-it-legal-for-private-citizens-to-impound-e-s).

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this impound yard could be found to be breaking the law, but it may not come to that.  This has only worked for him *so far* because this is a novel area of law, where very little in the way of precedent has been laid down.

This type of imaginative law-bending [is very typical](https://www.nwitimes.com/news/local/lake/lake-newsletter/lake-news/a-scrap-dealer-charged-with-stealing-a-railroad-span-still/article_fb09e1cc-6823-5df1-8251-bf180e3bced0.html) of people in the impound and scrap business.

But the other party is [no white knight](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2019/01/bird-sends-nastygram-reporter-describing-lawful-re-use-impounded-scooters).

### The no-lose scenario

It appears to me that the *true* goal of this enterprise is to  **resell these rather sturdy scooters on the used market**.  It works in his favor to acquire thousands of them, so he can spread the engineering cost of breaking the locking mechanism.

I suspect this started out as an impound/ransom scheme, on the logic that it's cheaper for the scooter companies to buyback their scooter than pay China for a new one; however the scooter companies aren't cooperating, and in fact seem to be willing to feed unlimited replacement scooters into the market. They seem to be gambling that he'll lose big.

He knew at the start this would either be one of the two above paths, or, the scooter companies would pull out of San Diego *entirely*. He is publicly in favor of the latter!  Which weakens his legal position, because it makes this look like a personal crusade; and **he has contrived a situation where he wins in every case**.  He collects impound fees, or gets free scooters, or personally kills a business model that offends him.  Judges tend to be especially skeptical of those.

### Left-handed ways of winning

The law could go his way.  But he may also be gambling that the [scooter companies will fold up](https://www.ft.com/content/0bf24c92-09c5-11e9-9fe8-acdb36967cfc), and he would be able to settle out on the scooters for pennies on the dollar with the bankruptcy trustee. There's [precedent for mass scooter business failure](https://www.theatlantic.com/photo/2018/03/bike-share-oversupply-in-china-huge-piles-of-abandoned-and-broken-bicycles/556268/). And the trustee would not want lengthy "make new law" litigation, and would cheerfully take a cash settlement. He sure won't want the scooters back.

But in the meantime, he's thick into a public relations campaign.  Because of the unwritten and untested law in this area, he's trying to motivate legislators into writing statute favorable to him, or even prejudice juries into thinking "That's just how society works". Hence the press coverage you are seeing.  He's definitely having an influence; the city of San Diego [endorsed his actions by imitation](https://fox5sandiego.com/2019/07/22/city-impounds-2500-scooters-during-comic-con-weekend/) at Comic Con.

### Problems with his approach

As discussed, he's rigged this situation *so wildly in his favor* that it will bear extreme scrutiny from judges. And when people do  things *this* imaginative, they often get  blind-sided by a legal issue they didn't see coming.

This person will have a big problem with **mitigation**. Everyone has a duty to mitigate (reduce) the other person's damages.  That is his blind-side.  Consider mitigation of an illegally parked *automobile*.

> Pure mitigation would say "move it to the nearest legal parking spot". Couple problems with this.  #1 when I return, I won't know where the car is, and will presume it stolen. This will cause me to abandon it in your new location, where it will be vandalized. And #2, cars can't be moved by hand; they need a tow, and those require $30-50 of net cost to the tower. Merely sending a towing bill to the vehicle registration address isn't likely to be collectible. For both reasons, a specific written law authorizes impounding **for cars**.

Here, this rationale falls apart.

- The companies are (by nature) highly capitalized and eminently collectible, so "impound to assure payment" is ridiculous.
- "so the owner knows where it is" also doesn't apply to scooter shares, since *any safe public location* will do (given the business model), and the units have GPS trackers and the companies have armies of tenders.
- "Too big for a human to move" is also inapplicable. As for inability/business, mitigation requires you do the easiest/cheapest thing that'll get the job done.  It prohibits swerving out of your way to use a very expensive option out of spite, which is the clear motivation of the shopkeepers.

The shopkeepers would already be on the hook for the difference between this guy's impound fees and 50 cents. However, because their motivations are transparent, I see where they have no defense at all.

### Also, they are circumventing the official system

Even moreso, the scooter companies **already have a system in place** for doing what these impounders are doing. They have an army of people who recover, reposition and charge scooters. This is crowdstaffed, and anyone can do it -- the impounders already could have joined that program, and be paid *the normal way*.

So it's not like the impounders are filling a need, which is what they are claiming in their press. They are circumventing the existing program, and replacing it with their own *much more expensive* program - hence words like "ransom" and "extortion".

What keeps you or I from doing the very same thing?  The only difference is we don't have a license to impound **cars**.

Also against the impounders is their "distributed yards" in various business' parking lots, which obscures who is in possession of the unit (the scooters have GPS/radio onboard). The steel container shell means it can't get radio signals out *at all*, which looks like concealment.

The bottom line is that this looks, walks and quacks like a speculative venture to steal scooters on a large scale or commit extortion, because it does not look like a *bona-fide* attempt to manage the problem of abandoned scooters.

Judges certainly do not like contrived situations that exist to create inflated service fees, as we have seen in Righthaven, Prenda, Molsky and numerous other harassment lawsuits.

### Possible defenses

First, the scooter companies could alter the EULA so that if you *take* a scooter to private property, **you are *renting* the scooter**, and make that EULA stick to anyone who does so.  That adds a financial peril to the situation and gives the scooter companies a basis to go on the offensive.

Second, remember the *duty to mitigate?* The owner has it, and the scooter company could help them by adding a button to the control panel marked "Remove from my private property", with an indicator confirming the company received the message (even better: ETA) or "please move to better cell reception". This would salt the earth even further for any legal argument in favor of would-be impounders.

That's not to say it's required; it's still *easy* for a business owner to push a scooter out to the curb.  And if it's not, because the scooter are a constant nuisance, remember:  the scooter companies **pay** their crowd-staff to collect scooters. A business could arrange with a collector to visit frequently, or keep a special eye on their business on the app -- and the scooter company would pay the freight on that.

Lastly, the scooter companies could do what rental **car** companies have been doing for decades -- pass through any legal consequences to the renter.  They know who last rented the scooter, where they left it, and when; pass the impound fee through.  Now, the impounder is no longer a folk hero fighting clueless outside companies. Now he's extorting his own town's citizens, and the tide will go against him in the city council meeting.

Comment: I have a question on the fees an impound yard charges. As far as I am aware, in California, tow and impound fees are set by the local PD, which determines the maximum rate the local tow yards charge for private tow and impound as well. If that understanding is correct, What arrangement regulates applicable fees for non-motor vehicle private impound?

Comment: Pushed? You'd have to *drag* it to the curb. You can't put garbage in the street, and aren't you supposed to never  block the public way (the sidewalk) with anything?

Comment: @Mazura of course, you should park the scooter just as sensibly as scooter users are asked to.  Even in a busy urban sidewalk, there are plenty of sensible places to put scooters.  I know because from time to time, I see a scooter there.  This isn't garbage, and regardless many people *do* put *precisely garbage* on the sidewalk every Thursday, with the understanding that it will be picked up within 18 hours or so.

Comment: Can we also place other items (besides scooters) on the sidewalk for rent (or sale)? I guess that should be a separate Question.

Comment: What if someone trips over the scooter I move off my land onto the public sidewalk? Who's liable for their injury?

Comment: Folks, this answer covers a lot of territory because it's trying to substantially cover all the angles. That inherently creates a lot of "surface area": with so much here it's very easy for something to seem offensive.  Please take that into account before DVing.  In other words please don't let this answer become an ["Aunt Sally"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aunt_Sally) for individual feelings on scooters :) I don't like them either, but there's a bunch of weird new law being crafted here, and that's what we're here to talk about.